# Error when activating Gmail API for my google service account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gmail-api, service-accounts

I'm getting this error when tring to activate gmail API in my project from https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/gmail-json.googleapis.com/overview :

> Spanner encountered a persistent error: generic::RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED:
>   Quota exceeded: chubby!mdb/apiserving-spanner in alloc
>   cloud_flex:us_global over user limit for [FLASH_SPACE].

[image]

What should I do to fix that ?
(My final goal is to update user email signature for my domain)

Answer (score 1):

Based from [Standard Error Responses](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/coreErrors#standard_errors), "quotaExceeded" indicates that limit per view has been reached or exceeded. Recommended action for such error is to retry using [exponential back-off](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/coreErrors#backoff) and you need to wait for at least one in-progress request for this view (profile) to complete.

For more information, you may also go through [Usage Limits](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/quota) and [Implementing Server-Side Authorization](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/web-server) .